# Chromium Sandbox on Mac OSX: Is it enabled by default?

Tags: web-browser, macos, sandbox

I have decided to finally replace the closed source and privately owned Google Chrome with the open-source Chromium on my Mac OSX 10.9.2 (Mavericks).

I have read the differences between both [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome):

And the article suggests that in Chromium, unlike Chrome, not always the Sandbox feature is enabled (and to open "about:sandbox" in the browser to confirm". Well when I open it in Chromium I just get the default "not found" page.

### Does that mean Chromium does not have sandbox protection on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reanimating :)

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-os-x#TOC-Temporarily-disabling-the-Sandbox

According to this it is enabled by default.